# PHP loop within a CCS-style with PHP variable

Tags: php, css

I need a temperaturescale with different degrees in a HTML table.
I use the next PHP script;

```
<div id="rec1"/>
<?php
$helegraden="72.2px;";
for ($x = 1; $x <= 3; $x++) {
echo '<div id="rec2" style="margin-left:72.2px;"/>';
}
?>
```

And mij CSS code is;

```
#rec2{
top: 0px;
float: left;
margin-top: 0px;    
width:1px;
height:50px;
background: blue;
}
```

But the PHP code did not work with the variable
style="margin-left:....
This is what it seposed to be;

http://www.ccvd.eu/downloads/scale.jpg

My excuses for my bad Englisch.

Comment: you are echoing as static string with no variable. Also you are not closing the `div`

Comment: Sorry there is some text disappeared. I try; <div id="rec2" style="margin-left: <?php echo $helegraden; ?>%;">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `id` is supposed to be unique, but you're generating multiple `div` elements with the same `id`. Use a `class` instead.

Second, close your `div` elements properly: `<div></div>`.

Third, either use your defined `$helegraden` inside of the loop:

```
echo '<div class="rec2" style="margin-left:' . $helegraden . '"></div>';
```

Or move that definition into `css`; don't apply inline styles.

```
echo '<div class="rec2"></div>';
```

```css
.rec2 {
  top: 0px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="rec2" style="margin-left:72.2px;"></div>
<div class="rec2" style="margin-left:72.2px;"></div>
<div class="rec2" style="margin-left:72.2px;"></div>
```

Comment: `<?php    $helegraden="72.2px;";  
for ($x = 1; $x <= 3; $x++) {  
echo '<div class="rec2" style="margin-left:' . $helegraden . '"></div>';  
}  
?>`     Did not do the job, it gives not one verticale line (rectangle)

Comment: It is now working, tnx. `<?php
echo '<div class="rec1" >';
for ($x = 1; $x <= 40; $x++) {
echo '<div class="rec2" style="margin-left:' . $tiendegraden . '"/>';
}
?>`